# Заполнения массива

Tags: python, pyqt5

Как сделать так чтобы элемент не заменялся, а как бы заполнял массив.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QDesktopWidget, 
    QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QInputDialog, QLabel, QHBoxLayout,
    QToolTip, QMessageBox, QLineEdit, QTextEdit,QFrame, QLCDNumber, QSlider)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont, QColor


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(800, 440)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('merge sort')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('web.png'))    

        self.btn = QPushButton('Enter array', self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.gettext)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        # Array input field
        self.lbl = QLabel('<b>Enter array:</b>', self)
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl)
        # output element
        self.le = QLabel(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.le)

    #  Asked whether you really sure you want to close
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
            "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()   

    # Makes the window was centered
    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter( cp )
        self.move(qr.topLeft()) 

    # Enter array
    def gettext(self):
        num, ok = QInputDialog.getInt(self, 'integer input dualog',
            'Enter element:')      
        if ok:
            self.le.setText(str(num))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    ex = Example()
    ex.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: 1. Слишком много ненужного кода. 2. Не нашел в коде или в вопросе озвученный массив

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот добавление через метод списков append:

```
# инициализация массива
self.arr = []

# добавления в массив
# Enter array
def getnum(self):
    num, ok = QInputDialog.getInt(self, 'integer input dualog', 'Enter element:')      
    if ok:
        self.arr.append(num)
        self.output.setText(str(self.arr))
```